# What is OverridableComponent and OverrideProps interface in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, interface, material-ui, overriding

Material UI uses and exposes `OverridableComponent` and `OverrideProps` interface.

But there is no where documented what are these and why and when do we use it?

Can someone explain please? Even a link to useful article would be appreciated.